# Cocoa installation: terminal showing 'Is a directory' error while getting POD file

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

[image]

I am always getting the same error i.e. `is a directory` when I try to execute the above bash script in the terminal to get pod file.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: I can hardly see anything on small screenshot, but you seem to be entering path first and then command `cd`. You should write command first and then target path.

Answer (score 0):

In the first couple lines, you appear to have an errant filepath in your command. Instead of `$ /Users/rgf...TestTable.xcodeproj cd`, it should have been `$ cd`. Your shell is complaining because the command–as you've written it–appears to be executing a directory, which isn't possible.